# Детский вопрос о библиотеках

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Сегодня в новостях канала *Euronews*: интервью с хозяином ***библиотеки инструментов***.

> Инструменты в этой мастерской находятся в постоянном обороте. Их берут напрокат для ремонта домов, ухода за садом, рукоделия или хобби...
> Проект стартовал в 2015 году. На сегодня у него более 400 подписчиков, которые платят 40 евро в год, чтобы брать инструменты сколько угодно...

Мы смотрели этот репортаж вместе с ребёнком.
Девочка (9 лет, третий класс) спросила: "Разве этот мужчина *библиотекарь*?"
Мы долго рассуждали, но так и не смогли понять — правильно ли название репортажа?

[Библиотека инструментов в брюссельском хозяйстве замкнутого типа](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SMnp_bkFyc)

Comment: Всем-всем спасибо большущее! Ребенок, правда, огорчился, что его вопрос не является полезным.

Comment: Римма, мне нравятся Ваши "детские" вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Дело в том, что это действительно вопросы ребенка.

Comment: Сомнений в этом никаких. Взял в кавычки, потому что вопросы-то серьезные!

Comment: Мы живем в разных городах. Девочка серьезно занимается спортом и очень любопытна. Мне не всегда *сразу* удается ответить на ее вопросы, но она знает, что *нам* здесь обязательно помогут разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Библиотека" инструментов в брюссельском хозяйстве замкнутого типа.***

В этом предложении надо поставить кавычки для обозначения переносного смысла, как и в слове "библиотекарь". В репортаже есть ключевая фраза – одалживают инструменты **как в библиотеке**.

БИБЛИОТЕКА, -и; ж. [греч. **biblíon** – **книга** и thēkē – хранилище, ящик] 1. Учреждение или отдел какого-л. учреждения, **собирающие и хранящие книги**, периодику, памятники письменности и т.п. для общественного пользования; здание, помещение для хранения и выдачи читателям таких изданий. Записаться в библиотеку. Брать книги в библиотеке.

В репортаже тоже описано  **хранилище, учреждение**, но собирающее не книги, а  инструменты. А почему же там **как в библиотеке?**

Такой тип экономики называется ***шеринг***  (от англ. ***share*** – делить). Шеринговая экономика несет в себе идею **совместного использования** товаров и услуг **вместо владения**.

Нет необходимости приобретать вещи в собственность, можно арендовать их на нужный срок, при этом значительно сэкономить и не захламлять жильё. Это особенно выгодно, если вечернее платье или дрель нужны вам раз в году.

**Формы** шеринга разнообразные. В данном случае "библиотекарь" – это собственник инструментов и организатор всего хозяйства. В "библиотеке" есть подписчики. Вы платите 40 евро в год (приобретаете **абонемент**) и можете на любой срок взять любой инструмент.

Интересно устроены современные **электронные библиотеки**. Там вы тоже покупаете **абонемент** на какой-то срок и можете скачивать доступные для этого книги. Но теперь это книги навсегда "ваши": вы можете скачивать их в любое время на любые устройства.

Есть программы для организации собственных библиотек. Так что при желании вы тоже можете стать **"библиотекарем".**

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Совместное_потребление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

https://www.litres.ru/

Answer (score 2):

В прямом смысле "библиотека" и переводится как хранилище книг. И даже неважно, могут ли оттуда брать напрокат книги читатели, либо хранилище просто эти книги держит. При этом библиотека не обязательно хранит книгу в виде стопки листов в корешке. В библиотеках хранят и свитки, и глиняные дощечки, и электронные книги.

Возможность собрать библиотеку из файлов расширила варианты употребления слова "библиотека" до собрания вообще любых файлов: есть библиотеки кодов, библиотеки тегов и даже библиотеки видео и фото, которые было бы корректнее называть видеотеками и фототеками.

Но человек привык упрощать. Мало кто, например, будет искать специфический термин "инсектариум" для обозначения стеклянного ящика с насекомыми. Скорее всего, человек вам скажет просто "аквариум", хотя никакой воды и рыбок там нет.
То же происходит и с "библиотекой". Человеку проще описать модель заведения знакомым словом, чем тратить время на поиск узкопрофильного термина, с которым он незнаком.

Теперь от абстракции к частному, к вашему вопросу. Ребёнок в этом случае справедливо сомневается, потому что слово "библиотека" не применяется в отношении проката инструментов. Это именно прокат. Там нет ни книг, ни признаков, которые, по моему мнению, предполагает хранилище: обеспечение сбережения материалов, а не их износ.

Также обращу внимание, что до сих пор в употреблении библиотека была и оставалась хранилищем информации в любых формах. Инструменты не несут информации.

Comment: Мы еще раз посовещались... И "порешали": мужчину надо было назвать лавочником или прокатчиком.

Comment: Я за прокатчика. Лавочник, судя по всему, продаёт насовсем.

Comment: Очень хочется *особо* отметить Ваш ответ, но смущает вот это предложение: *Там нет ни книг, ни признаков, которые, по моему мнению, предполагает хранилище: обеспечение **сохранности хранимых** материалов.* (Тавтология, что-ли?) В данном случае, мне кажется, хранилище — это просто место, помещение для хранения, сбережения чего-либо. (https://endic.ru/efremova/Hranilische-117339.html)

Comment: Заменил тавтологию на аналогичное высказывание. Я считаю, что в том-то и дело, что для хранилища ключевой функцией будет "сбережение", особенно если мы говорим о библиотеке. А когда речь об инструментах, это скорее склад, где нет идеи держать вещи в идеальных условиях, как в музее, а нужно просто положить что-то до надобности.

Answer (score 2):

**Это мой второй ответ (внеконкурсный).**

Мне тоже нравятся твои вопросы, я считаю их **очень полезными** и поставила тебе лайк!

А давай вместе подумаем, **как назвать** хранилище инструментов и человека, работающего там.

Для этого надо посмотреть примеры суффиксов мужских профессий, а также названий хранилищ чего-либо. Они должны быть образованы от слова «инструмент».

У меня такие варианты: ***инструментотека, инструментарий.***

Сравнить: гербарий, планетарий, депозитарий (хранение денег и ценных финансовых бумаг), океанарий, дельфинарий, дендрарий. Суффикс АРИЙ имеет значение собрание чего-либо для различных целей, хотя по значению эти слова очень разные. Но такая уж особенность у языка.

А для профессии можно использовать такие слова: ***инструментальщик, интструментник, инструментщик.***

Правда, два последних не очень благозвучные, а слово «инструментальщик» уже есть в словаре: **ИНСТРУМЕНТАЛЬЩИК**, -а; м. Рабочий, специалист по изготовлению инструментов (1 зн.). Работать инструментальщиком. Слесарь-инструментальщик.

Значение не совсем подходит, но ведь мы можем «расширить» это значение и внести наше слово в словарь под цифрой *два*.

Такая же история со словом "инструментарий": ИНСТРУМЕНТАРИЙ, -я; м. Совокупность инструментов (1 зн.), употребляемых в какой-л. специальности. Хирургический и.  Здесь значение слова тоже придется **подправить**.

Ну вот, наш "проект" на заданную тему для школы готов.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Sharon, за *персональное* обращение к **А.** Пыфф! Столько внимания к вопросу — она даже растерялась (а ведь поначалу не было никакого интереса). Благодарим всех еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Читальня — более подходящее слово, отражающее лишь порядок или принцип работы этой **мастерской**-*напрокат*, один из возможных смыслов которой формулируется вопросом: «Хотите научиться новому?» Если «у вас нет нужных инструментов» или необходимых условий и кое-каких нехитрых расходных материалов, то здесь устроены рабочие места, подключены приборы, станки. А помогут вам советом и делом — отремонтировать, восстановить внешний вид предмета, — такие же рукастые гости.

Такому объекту дал бы название «Сам себе мастер», да вот беда — есть такой журнал.

**Правильно ли название репортажа?** В рекламном репортаже использованы сведения, полученные от владельца.

**Этот мужчина библиотекарь?** Связать напрямую — профессию (должность) специалиста с назначением (названием) заведения — удаётся лишь иногда; чаще  подобные вопросы не воспринимаются языком, особенно при минимуме штата сотрудников и множественности задач предприятия, как решаемые и насущные.

Comment: *Напрокат* вроде слитно пишется.